# Display post only when attribute is applied

Tags: php, wordpress

The below code is outputting 6 events on my homepage. It seems to be choosing the 6 by post ID. I want to change this so that it will only show a post on the homepage if the custom attribute called **HOMEPAGE** is added to the post.

How do I do this?

```
<?php if(is_front_page()): ?>
    <div id="eventBoxes">
        <ul>
        <?php $vReturn = eme_get_events_list('limit=6'); ?> 

        <?php 

            $vReturn = explode("</li>",$vReturn);

            foreach($vReturn as $item) {
                if(strpos($item,'<div id="homepage">yes</div>') !== false) {
                    echo $item;
                }
            }

        ?>

        </ul>
        <br class="clear" />


<?php else: ?>
    <div id="content">

    <?php echo the_content(); ?>

    </div>          

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I want to keep the limit to 6 posts.

Comment: what is `eme_get_events_list` ?

Comment: @BrianLee 'eme_get_events_list' is the call to display the list of events from the plugin

Comment: @paislee It's using Events Made Easy plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this:

```
<?php if(is_front_page()): ?>
<div id="eventBoxes">
    <?php if(isset($_POST['YOUR_POST_PARAMETER']) && $_POST['YOUR_POST_PARAMETER'] == 'YOUR_POST_PARAM_VALUE') : ?>
    <ul>
    <?php $vReturn = eme_get_events_list('limit=6'); ?> 

    <?php 

        $vReturn = explode("</li>",$vReturn);

        foreach($vReturn as $item) {
            if(strpos($item,'<div id="homepage">yes</div>') !== false) {
                echo $item;
            }
        }

    ?>

    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <br class="clear" />
<?php else: ?>
<div id="content">

<?php echo the_content(); ?>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It is also a good practice to check whether You have any items to list within `<ul>` - if not, then You will write an empty `<ul></ul>` to the HTML, that leads to invalid HTML... Try using `count()` on the returned array and if it is `> 0` then write `<ul> <?php ... your code here ... ?> </ul>`

Comment: Would I put HOMEPAGE in as the parameters? Sorry, bit of an amateur :(

Comment: let's assume you want to show it only when there is post variable `'show_events'` and it has a value of 1 (one). Then my IF condition would look like: `<?php if(isset($_POST['show_events']) && $_POST['show_events'] == 1) : ?>` - try it...

Comment: I put it as `<?php if(isset($_POST['HOMEPAGE']) && $_POST['HOMEPAGE'] == 'yes') : ?>`. It stopped all the other's from showing but when I added the `HOMEPAGE` attribute to a post and gave it a value of `yes`, it still shows no events on homepage.

Comment: Are variables the same as attributes?

Comment: @Kelvin: It depends whether you really use a POST, or pass attributes in URL - then it is GET and you will need to change $_POST for $_GET.

Comment: Tried just changing them to $_GET, still not showing up events. No idea what to do :(

Comment: @Kelvin: OK, what does the request or URL look like, when You want to show the vents, and what when don't? Are You sure Your URL looks like this: `http://{...}/?HOMEPAGE=yes` when You are checking $_GET and want to show the events?

Comment: They're not in the Post section, they're Events. So I'm not sure how to define them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7215/discussion-between-kelvin-and-shadyyx)

Answer (score 0):

Is the HOMEPAGE attribute a post meta value?  if so, you would need to use the [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function.

To check if a post has the HOMEPAGE custom attribute you would do something like this:

```
$homepage = get_post_meta(the_id);

if (!empty($homepage)){
// you've found a post with a valid home page attribute.

}
```

HTH

Comment: The HOMEPAGE attribute is a custom attribute added to in the post page. I just want it so that, when applied, it acts as a trigger to show that event on the page.